# check-in policies visual studio - a check changeset comments if are in the defined template

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, stylecop, policies

Exist any way how to create custom check-in policies for changeset comments in the defined template?
For example, the template is: 
`"{shortcut}: {number} - {check-in comment}"`

Answer (score 0):

First to say, there is no build-in way to prefill the comment section within the pending changes.

A workaround is creating your own custom check-in policy to do what you're looking for. First use the Check-In Policy that requires comments, and then take it one step further which require comments that include a specifically formatted string. Or make the comment auto start with some particular text.

Detail steps about how to create custom check-in policy please refer below tutorials, moreover, this is **a way of setting for the all team members**.:

- [Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy](http://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html)
- [Creating a custom check-in policy pack that works with multiple
  versions of Visual Studio.](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/01/creating-custom-check-in-policy-pack.html)

Lastly, they're not perfect also with some limitations. This is a cultural problem, trying to solve it with technology is not a good way. Please also take a look at Daniel Mann's answer in this similar question here: [How can i force meaningful checkin comments on Team Foundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635152/how-can-i-force-meaningful-checkin-comments-on-team-foundation)